# Java JSON POST not formatting correctly

Tags: java, json, http

I'm trying to create a method that will send a POST request given a url and a JSONArray. The excerpt of that code is as follows:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("id", -12);
        obj.put("title", "titlevalue");
        obj.put("body", "bodyvalue");
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("[" + obj + "]");

        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

        System.out.println(arr.toString());

        OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        wr.write(arr.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if (con.getResponseCode() != 201) // make sure request is successful
            throw new Exception("Error code " + con.getResponseCode());

        String str = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        System.out.println(str);
```

The first print statement shows me that my input is correctly formatted

```
[{
    "id": -12,
    "title": "titlevalue",
    "body": "bodyvalue"
}]
```

This is how I want it, however after writing to the outputstream the second print statement shows me that it's not correctly formatted for JSON at all, there's weird escape characters throughout and it's not picking up the key/value pairs.

```
{
    "[{\"id\":-12,\"title\":\"titlevalue\",\"body\":\"bodyvalue\"}]": "",
    "id": 101
}
```

Am I doing something wrong during the POST?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be in the line:

```
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("[" + obj + "]");
```

I suspect that `obj` is converted to a string at this point and your `JSONArray` contains just a single string. That is, `"[" + obj + "]"` has the effect of calling `obj.toString()` and creating a single string which is passed in to the constructor.

This means that when you write it out, the single string has the embedded quotes escaped. The `System.out.println(arr.toString());` is actually misleading. You haven't set up your object as you intended.

The solution might be as simple as:

<del>---JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(obj);---</del>

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(obj);
```

Comment: I see what you mean by having the embedded quotes escaped, the reason I did it the way I did is because JSONArray doesn't accept a JSONObject as a parameter nor allows a string that doesn't start with a square bracket, so I added the two square brackets at the beginning and the end to make sure it is valid when constructing the JSONArray.

I tried doing your edits and also trying obj.toString, but it gives me the "must start with '['" error. Just to try it out, I tried changing it so that the JSONObject is written rather than the JSONArray, but the same weird formatting occurs.

Comment: I wasn't able to test my possible solution. Have a read through the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray). This has some insights into the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", -12);
obj.put("title", "titlevalue");
obj.put("body", "bodyvalue");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
arr.put(obj);
```

Explanation: As Dave explained by placing the String surrounded with "[" and "]" you introducing escape characters.  Rather, just put the object created into the array. A better approach will be to use GSON or JACKSON for parsing which you can easily find tutorials in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using GSON Library which is a really simple to convert any java objects to JSON string.

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
String json = gson.toJson(myObject);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why GSON?

Comment: GSON is a fairly simple library which autodetects the structure of your class (per se MAPS , LISTS, SETS) all of them can be represented as JSON. GSON supports every java object to convert it into JSON in just one line of code which is less cumbersome.